# Does the British government have control on what can the BBC broadcast?

Tags: united-kingdom, media

**Edited**

Does the British government have control on what can the BBC broadcast?

Comment: The price of containers went up worldwide because of the pandemic-driven "traffic jams" in shipping.  So it would have been pretty inaccurate for the BBC to broadcast that, which was blaming it on Brexit.

Comment: Can you please provide supporting links for this?

Comment: @Fizz the stuff about paperwork seems Brexit related, starting around 2:00 in the video.

Comment: Downvoting because, while the headline of this question is a valid one, the body makes it sound like you're seeking to push a view and not actually learn about politics.

Comment: @Mocas: sure, e.g. https://www.voanews.com/a/economy-business_no-quick-fix-shipping-crisis-creating-supply-chain-bottlenecks/6210070.html ; http://web.archive.org/web/20210910022456/https://time.com/6073233/shipping-costs-surge-price-hike-goods/ ; https://reuters.com/business/china-us-container-shipping-rates-sail-past-20000-record-2021-08-05/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is no. The BBC's funding is written into law so beyond regulation of content on the airwaves generally through OFCOM (The UK's equivalent to the US' FCC), there's not a lot the British government can do about BBC content.

[Not that they don't try now and again.](https://www.voanews.com/a/europe_uk-government-odds-media-set-review-bbc-funding/6183738.html) But the existence of headlines like "UK Government at Odds with BBC" further drives home to the point that the BBC is rather it's own thing.

Such policy efforts to attack the foundation of the BBC's funding are likely to draw the attention of those who make decisions at BBC, and MI5 does still retain some vetting power over those who will cover wartime content, or have access to classified information, but these are *de minimis* sources of influence.  (MI5 used to secretly vet many of the people working at the BBC, and during that time I'd say the gov't had a very strong influence over the organization, but this largely ended in the mid-to-late 90s.)

As public broadcasting companies go, the BBC is very nearly the gold standard for independence from the government, despite arguably depending on the government for its funding.

Comment: That was my understanding/expectation, but how do you explain the BBC not taking much about effects of Brexit on the UK economy?

Comment: @Mocas As far as I can tell, "why aren't the BBC doing XYZ" is a question of internal motivation, and that's explicitly not something we can answer on this site. "Why aren't the BBC doing XYZ *much*" is even worse, because then you've got the subjectivity of "How much is 'not much'? How much *should* they be talking about it?"

Comment: @Mocas: they surely seem to still talk some about it  e.g. https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/m000xpcm ; https://www.bbc.com/news/business-58395401 They did sorta hide the Brexit tag so it's no longer on the front page, but only on the UK one https://www.bbc.com/news/politics/uk_leaves_the_eu It seem kinds understandable as it's no longer the prime-time issue that used to be. If that's what your q is really about edit it, so it's not this [XY question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) that it is now.

Comment: @Mocas: frankly it looks like they cover the issue at least once a week https://www.bbc.com/news/av/uk-58521211 Note that UK (and actually EU) driver shortage is not the same issue as the global container shipping problems, but it surely compounds it.